# Return a string in a HTTP response as JSON using express JS

Tags: json, express

I want to return a string in a HTTP response as JSON using express JS. I am trying this but I am getting error. What am I doing wrong?

```
msg = '{"foo": "bar"}';
msgJSON = JSON.parse(msg);
res.status(200).send(msgJSON);
```

I need to be a string because it is generated concatenating key-value pairs

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: do you get that error with the example code you posted, or just with the programmatically built string? I see nothing wrong with what you've posted aside from some extra steps you don't need.

Comment: @DanCrews Indeed I was getting the error with the programatically built string. I was doing it wrong but thanks to your answer I managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your edit, you don't need to parse the object. You can just send the data:

```
res.set('content-type', 'application/json');
res.status(200).send(msg);
```

Comment: I forgot to add ' ' in order to be a string, sorry. I updated the question

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just by the way, why if I use res.status(200).json(msg) instead of res.status(200).send(msg) the response is between " ": "response"